# Sounds are being played at the same time

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

I'm making a school project that allows plants to 'talk'. As in when the plant is in an un-ideal environment (low or high soil moisture, not ideal temperature or humidity and not enough light). I have currently made some demo code for my presentation as the real code has real thresholds and is hard to trigger instantly during the presentation.
The problem im facing is that the sound is almost always cut off by another one, how can i stop this, also the recordings are all 7 seconds or less.

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
//-----------------DEMO---CODE-------
#define DHTPIN 3
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
#define SOIL_MOISTURE_PIN A0
#define LIGHT_SENSOR_PIN 2
#define TEMP_THRESHOLD 25.0
#define HUMIDITY_THRESHOLD 60
#define LIGHT_THRESHOLD 1  // 1 for dark, adjust as needed
#define LOWER_SM_THRESHOLD 20 // Adjust as needed
#define UPPER_SM_THRESHOLD 50 // Adjust as needed
#define LCD_ADDR 0x27  // I2C address of the LCD
#define LCD_COLUMNS 16
#define LCD_ROWS 2
#define MESSAGE_INTERVAL 20000  // 20 seconds in milliseconds

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(10, 11);  // RX, TX for DFPlayer
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(LCD_ADDR, LCD_COLUMNS, LCD_ROWS);

unsigned long lastTempTrigger = 0;
unsigned long lastHumidityTrigger = 0;
unsigned long lastSoilMoistureTrigger = 0;
unsigned long lastLightTrigger = 0;

void setup() {
  dht.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
  myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial);

  myDFPlayer.volume(30);

  // Initialize the LCD
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Initializing...");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Plantastic!");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("System Ready");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {
  float temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  float humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  int lightValue = digitalRead(LIGHT_SENSOR_PIN);
  int soilMoistureValue = analogRead(SOIL_MOISTURE_PIN);
  int soilMoisturePercentage = 100 - (map(soilMoistureValue, 0, 1023, 0, 100));

  if (temperature > TEMP_THRESHOLD && millis() - lastTempTrigger >= MESSAGE_INTERVAL) {
    myDFPlayer.play(3);  // Play "Too Hot" message
    lastTempTrigger = millis();
  } else if (temperature < TEMP_THRESHOLD && millis() - lastTempTrigger >= MESSAGE_INTERVAL) {
    myDFPlayer.play(1);  // Play "Too Cold" message
    lastTempTrigger = millis();
  }

  if (round(humidity) < HUMIDITY_THRESHOLD && millis() - lastHumidityTrigger >= MESSAGE_INTERVAL) {
    myDFPlayer.play(2);  // Play "Low Humidity" message
    lastHumidityTrigger = millis();
  }

  if (soilMoisturePercentage < LOWER_SM_THRESHOLD && millis() - lastSoilMoistureTrigger >= MESSAGE_INTERVAL) {
    myDFPlayer.play(6);  // Play "Thirsty" message
    lastSoilMoistureTrigger = millis();
  } else if (soilMoisturePercentage > UPPER_SM_THRESHOLD && millis() - lastSoilMoistureTrigger >= MESSAGE_INTERVAL) {
    myDFPlayer.play(5);  // Play "Enough Water" message
    lastSoilMoistureTrigger = millis();
  }

  if (lightValue == 1 && millis() - lastLightTrigger >= MESSAGE_INTERVAL) {
    myDFPlayer.play(4);  // Play "It's dark in here" message
    lastLightTrigger = millis();
  }

  // Update the LCD display
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("T: ");
  lcd.print(temperature, 2);
  lcd.print(" H: ");
  lcd.print(humidity, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("SM: ");
  lcd.print(soilMoisturePercentage);
  lcd.print("% L: ");
  lcd.print(lightValue == LIGHT_THRESHOLD ? "Dark" : "Light");

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: You could check, if something is playing before executing play()

Comment: no the first bit of sound plays, like the first second or half second but it is then cut off by another sound so you can't hear t completely

Comment: Can't you just wait for the sound to end before continuing? If you loose an iteration because of the sound being played is probably not an issue (you're updating at most every second anyway)

Comment: I'm not talking of the user waiting the sounds to be finished. What you describe indicates that you execute the `play()` function, before the last sound ended. The dfplayer should also have a command, which will return the play status. If you insert an if clause for every call of `play()` to check if something is already playing, then you can prevent this interruption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches which address the problem of not playing a sound to completion.

1. Place a delay loop after each call to myDFPlayer.play() designed to last as long as the played sound. This is likely the most straight forward solution.  However, adding delays where no other code is able to run is considered bad programming form.  It also creates problem when adding new features to the program.
2. Create a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) where the loop() function has no delays.  Instead use a variable to track the state the state machine is in and only change that variable when the conditions to go to the next state have been satisfied.  For instance, do nothing until a threshold (dryness, light, ect) has been crossed.  At which point switch to the state where you play back the associated sound & clear that threshold flag.  Do not exit that state until millis() has increased past the duration of the played sound.  Finally, repeat these state transitions for any other thresholds that have been crossed.  Complex behaviors dealing with how long before repeating a sound can then be added with additional states.